# SSH с AWS Amazon с linux как обменяться ключами?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

Привет всем. Новичек в linux. Пытаюсь понять, после того, как я создал инстанс на AWS Amazon, скачал ключ "xxxx.pem", могу зайти на сервер из терминала линукса, соединение есть, мне все равно надо создавать еще ключи для ssh? Как? Еще - хочу прикрутить Filezilla, там нужен пароль? но у меня же нет никакого пароля... он берется после обмена этими ключами? спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Привет! Пару ключей для ssh можно создать на машине, с которой ты подключаешся. 
Это делается коммандой `ssh-keygen`, например:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Она создаст пару ключей `id_rsa` и `id_rsa.pub` в папке .ssh твоей домашней директории, короткий путь к ней будет такой - `~/.ssh/`.

Далее, можно скопировать публичный ключ на сервер, в домашнюю директорию вашего пользователя. Это можно сделать коммандой `ssh-copy-id`:

`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@example.com`

где *user* - имя твоего пользователя, *example.com* - адрес твоего сервера.

По поводу Filezilla, он понимает формат PEM. Этот файл можно указать через Preferences > Settings > Connection > SFTP > "Add key file".

По пути он предложит сконвертировать файл в ppk формат, соглашайся.

Новый файл ключа должен появится в списке доступных ключей. Если этого не произошло, то нажми *Add keyfile* и выбери его самостоятельно.

Как только ключ будет импортирован в Filezilla, Filezilla начнёт использовать его автоматически при подключении к твоему серверу.

Когда будешь создавать подключение к серверу, протокол должен быть SFTP.

[Видео пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI)